# NodeJS code worked until moved to windows Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I was messing with nodeJS on my computer, and got a client and server file working. When I got on my server remote host, I installed nodeJS and all the dependencies. The nodeJS server runs successfully, but when a client tries to connect, it doesn't do anything. I setup the server/client on port 3000. Could this be a problem with the server firewall? I realize this may be generic, but I am just looking for any possibilities. All the code on the server is the same, and I know I installed node and the dependencies correctly. Thanks

Comment: Most servers won't have an open port 3000. You probably will need to use a reverse proxy like nginx to forward traffic on e.g. port 80 to internal port 3000.

Comment: Look at the Windows Firewall to make sure that the correct port is open -- you don't necessarily need a reverse proxy, but that approach can work as well.